# jQuery Make Radio Button not clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

Is it possible to make a radio button 'unclickable'/ 'unselectable' without 'disabling' it?

For aesthetic reasons I need to know if this is possible and how it might be achieved.

Current code as follows:

```
<input name='example' value='1' type='radio'/>
<input name='example' value='2' checked='checked' type='radio'/>
<input name='example' value='3' type='radio'/>
<input name='example' value='4' type='radio'/>
<input name='example' value='5' type='radio'/>
```

Comment: What's wrong with `disabled`?

Comment: @MarcellFülöp - it 'greys out' the radio button, so, ideally, I'm looking for a solution that works like 'disabled' but keeps the look of the original radio button.

Comment: I don't know what you're doing, but it's almost always (99%) best to just go with what the user's familiar with. You may have aesthetic concerns but breaking their concepts about clickable radio buttons may be even more of a nuisance.

Comment: @bbill - appreciate the feedback - this is being used as an 'example' - i.e. a set of instructions so the user can see how to complete a form.  Hence why I need them to 'look' the same but don't want the user to be able to actually click/ change anything.

Comment: you can use css to change the appearance of disabled inputs, which preserve accessibility not present when using js to change defaults...

Comment: I see. Didn't mean to question what you were doing, of course. Good luck! :)

Comment: @bbill - no problems, not taken that way at all!  Appreciate the feedback and comments, I appreciate that questions are not always 100% clear!

Comment: @dandavis - any examples?  The jQuery works a treat but I would be interested to see a CSS alternative.

Comment: What does `readonly` do? Have you tried it?

Comment: :disabled { cursor: not-allowed; }  reset the user-agent css as shown in inspect element to customize.

Comment: @dandavis - cheers - will have a look into this.

Comment: If that is your endgame, check out the edit to my post :) I'm off now, good luck

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To preserve the checked/unchecked state of the radio inputs without using `disabled` (which would be far simpler), you *could* use the following:

```
// select the relevant radio input elements:
$('input[name="example"]')
    // bind a change-event handler using 'on()':
    .on('change', function(){
        // re-select the same elements:
        $('input[name="example"]')
            // set the 'checked' property back to the default (on page-load) state:
            .prop('checked', function(){
                return this.defaultChecked;
            });
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4x9tS/).

References:

- [Attribute-equals (`[attribute="value"]`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Comment: Perfect as it deals only with those buttons call 'example' - exactly what I was looking for.  Appreciate that David.

Answer (score 4):

*Based on one of your comments on your question ( you dont want to submit them, but show them a result/preview form), an edit to this post (original below):*

**Don't wrap the elements in a form**. If you don't need submitting, remove the form from it and all elements will look the same, but wont submit anything. Don't give any of the inputs a name,  ét voila.

---

You can counter the default action from a lot of elements with [preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/):

```
$('input[name="example"]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The way I use the name attribute isnt limited to the name. You can select all achors based on href: `$('a[href="/example"]')`, or any other attribute. It's worth to note that adding a class and select based on class will be faster than basing it on property, but always use at least a tagname to limit the selector.

[With a small jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2KR35/).

---

`e.preventDefault()` prevents more than a click. You can use it:

```
$('a').on('click', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); /* eg use pushstate safely now */}); // hijack anchors
$('form').on('submit', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); /* eg trigger custom validation here*/}); // stop submitting
```

---

Based in Ciel's topic, I got a third one, cssbased. This will add an invisible 'section' (might need to add a z-index) over the radiobutton. This requires no Javascript or html changes:

```
input[type="radio"]{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

input[type="radio"]:after{
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Martijn, appreciate that.

Comment: I noticed you want something for that input specificly, so editted my post a bit, with some explanation

Comment: That's an interesting solution as it negates the need to use jQuery, cheers.

Comment: Yeah, I use this method to hide my checkboxes and radio buttons so I can style them better without needing complex behavior.

Comment: You mean my css edit? Might need to tweak it just a bit, bit I hope the principle is clear :) Tip: Bavk the `:after{background:red}` to see what you're doing

Comment: Yeah, except I use `:before` instead. I've found it to be less troublesome. I kept running into trouble trying to style these controls, no matter what I did I always ran into issues where they would 'bleed' in one browser or another. I needed to hide them so I could put styling on top, but making them invisible meant they refused to work with things like MVVM, so this is actually the solution I contrived instead.

Comment: @Ciel - off topic - I've been looking at styling radio buttons to get a consistent look across browsers - any suggestions?! (cheeky I know!)

Comment: I do: Dont style them. Make a label with a span and the radiobutton, offset the input out of sight, make the span round with a border and outline. You style the span, not the input, because the styling the input is nearly impossible

Comment: Yes, I have a very good one for you @Homer_J. I will post it momentarily.

Comment: Alright, I've posted some of it. My repo isn't responding right now, I think that the box it is on got turned off with a power outage. I'll try to get it verbatim to you soon.

Comment: Hey @Martijn, I thought I would point something out. Your answer here does work, but keep in mind that by using the `::after` pseudo-selector, you're making it hard to target or mutate later. This was how I first did it too, but I then began to discover that the behavior functioned differently between FireFox and Chrome, because of the way they render the `box model`. That is what led me to the solution I posted, of using an actual `span` or `div`.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using pointer-events: none ? It prevents mouse clicks from doing anything.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

```
input[name="example"] {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: By gosh, it does! Knew there had to be a simple way to do it. This deserves some +1's, I think.

Answer (score 2):

If you really have to...
This hack works. http://jsfiddle.net/TTwbB/363/

```
$(':radio').click(function(){
    this.checked=false;
});
```

You could also listen to the `change` event if you want more flexibility.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply, appreciated.

Comment: No, this doesn't work: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/TTwbB/364/), it *always* unselectively unchecks the `input` (which causes the default-checked inputs to become unchecked).

Comment: Thank you, David - that makes sense. I made something quick because it seems like the OP isn't terribly concerned about that; maybe if he'd mentioned it, it would have been an issue. But when you ask for unselectable radio buttons, are you really going to want them selected by default? :)

Comment: @bbill - appreciate the feedback but as explained above and also in the code I supplied - this is to be used as an instruction and it does need an option to be pre-selected.

Comment: If there's a radio input checked by default in the demo code then *yes*, it seems quite likely that there might well be an input checked by default in the code itself.

Comment: Good observation! I've been too hasty.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I have found to do this is to simply place a little invisible "block" over it.

```
<div style="position: relative;">
   <input type="checkbox" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left; 0;" />
   <span style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 24px; height: 24px; display: block; z-index: 2; background: transparent; content: " ";"> </span>
</div>
```

This just covers it with a little layer that they can't click through, but it isn't fool proof.

Here is a working example. It isn't much, and it leaves a lot to be desired, but if you contain your whole `checkbox` in the same `div` and give them some class identifiers, it is pretty simple to use jQuery or other tools to arrange these as you want to if they need to shuffle around.

## [jsBin - 'Cover' checkbox](http://jsbin.com/xuhajida/1/edit)

This isn't very good, as I'm scrambling around trying to find it, but my repository isn't responding right now, but this is the gist of how I do it independently. I'm a fan of using non-value attributes, you can do it in a lot of different ways. I am using LESS right here, if you want the CSS, you should be able to click on the dropdown option to have it compile to pure CSS.

## [jsBin - 'Skinnable' checkboxes](http://jsbin.com/qofiba/2/edit)

In my actual project I have it a lot larger in scope, but basically you can declare any containing element as `skinnable`, and it'll establish the rudimentary features. If you want an input to be blocked, but visible, you declare it `obstructed`, and then you mark whatever you want to block it with with `obstruction`.

I have obviously cheesed this sample just a bit, as my actual repository doesn't seem to be responding, so if I can get to it I'll update this post a bit later.

## HTML

```
  <div skinnable>
    <input type="checkbox" obstructed />
    <span obstruction>
      <div skinned>
      </div>
    </span>
  </div>
```

## LESS

```
div[skinnable] {
  position: relative;

  input[obstructed] {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1
  }

  div[obstruction],
  span[obstruction]{
    position: absolute;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    display: block;
    background: transparent;
    content: " ";
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
  }

  div[skinned], 
  span[skinned] {
    background: blue;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    z-index: 3;
    display: block;
    content: " ";
  }

  div[green] {
    background-color: green;
  }
}
```

So you can basically set up `skinned` to be anything you want. If you decide you want to work with 3rd party libraries, like `iCheck`, you can easily `hide` or `show` by these attributes.

```
$('[obstruction]').hide();
```

You can do a lot of amazing things with this, I've only shown blocking them with colored blocks, but honestly it's pretty endless.

If you want them to be interactive **and** skinned, then you can remove the `obstructed` attribute, and use the `obstruction` attribute for interaction.

```
$('[obstruction]').on('click', function(e) {
   $(e).closest('input').checked(); // you can easily interact with them!
});
```

Comment: The checkbox doesnt have to be absolute at all :)

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I wrote it completely from memory so it may be a bit off.

Comment: I hope you dont mind, I added a variant of this to my own answer, based on yours (but csc3 :) )

Comment: I particularly like using this method because it doesn't require any kind of actual interaction with the `input`, it's like laying a transparency over a picture so that it doesn't smudge. If you have any interest, I can demonstrate how I use it more effectively, but I use it to hide the default check boxes so that I can replace them with skinned ones, without as much fancy HTML as things like `icheck`.

Comment: No, I don't mind at all. Using your method is actually how I do it, using the pseudo-element. I just typed from memory really quickly and forgot to do it that way

Comment: Thanks Ciel - I quite like this as (although I asked for a jQuery solution) it offers a different take - thanks.

Comment: If you will give me a few moments, I will get you the very, very exact code I use and add it onto this. Thank you for the up vote as well, I appreciate it.

Comment: There we go. It isn't the whole thing, since my repository seems to be unresponsive, but it is much of it. I actually have a cool solution that integrates well with bootstrap, if I can get my repo to respond, I'll load it up here later.

Comment: I go with an actual `div` or `span` instead of `::before` or `::after` because that gives me an element to use for skinning however I want. It also gives me an element that can receive clicks and interactions to change state. So it is slightly more code, but it produces more versatile results.

Comment: I am a really big fan of verbose, clear HTML with few actual inline styles. I know it isn't very conventional, but it's how I code, and it works well for me. You can of course adjust them however you desire, the principle is extremely simple.

Comment: I will also add, doing it this way means you never have to worry about interactivity with things like validators, MVVM systems, or anything of that nature. A lot of methods that move things around and try to redraw the checkboxes in strange ways, those start to become obtuse when you have to begin validating or model binding. This method is free and void of any of those problems.

Comment: And that, of course, has the added benefit of naturally and gracefully deprecating into older browsers, so if your page is opened up by something that doesn't have javascript, or cannot understand the HTML attribute freedom that HTML5 gives, it won't fall apart. It just loses some aesthetics.

Comment: Oh, and the jQuery solution, I use `iCheck` when necessary. You can find it here: https://github.com/fronteed/iCheck/

Comment: What is more, the solution I just gave you can cooperate with `iCheck` pretty well to give you the functionality of non-clickable jQuery skinned checkboxes, if you find a need for it.

Comment: Really appreciate that, will look into iCheck as well.  Valuable feedback, thanks Ciel.

Comment: Hey @Homer_J, I have some more examples, but they are in private code that I cannot just give out to the public. I'm pretty busy today, but if I have the time I'll try to snip some of it out and show you. This technique is working VERY well for me so far, though.

Comment: Also, I really, really appreciate all the up votes. Fighting for reputation is extremely hard.

Comment: Hey @Homer_J, as I promised I have compiled all of my information into a single place and started up a chat room with you, you may look at it there at your own convenience. This is just one of the ways I am using both my above technique, and `icheck`, within my own system - modified to suit the needs of my specific layout and stuff.  I attempted to break it up into pieces and segments so you can examine only what you have to change to make it do what you want.

Comment: @Homer_J, I believe you can get to the room with this link - but if not, let me know. I am new to this "chat" thing on stack overflow. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55913/room-for-ciel-and-homer-j